# npm won't install from package.json within project

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, npm, osx-mountain-lion

On my macbook air I can only install npm packages globally using sudo but anytime I go into a local directory and try to install a local package without the -g it gives me errors.

```
 npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/mmarze/.npm/53951495-coffee-script.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/mmarze/.npm/53951495-coffee-script.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mmarze/.npm/53951495-coffee-script.lock' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mmarze/sandbox/node.js/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.61
npm ERR! path /Users/mmarze/.npm/53951495-coffee-script.lock
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/mmarze/.npm/53951495-coffee-script.lock'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mmarze/sandbox/node.js/test/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm and I can't get it to install anything locally, and if I use sudo to install locally then my local user doesn't have write access to them. How can I fix this?

Comment: Who is the owner of /Users/mmarze/.npm? Anything interesting in /Users/mmarze/sandbox/node.js/test/npm-debug.log?

Comment: Looks like you may have done a `sudo npm install ...` without `-g`, i.e. installed npm packages in your home as the root user. Either clear your `.npm` directory or `chown -R mmarze.mmarze ~/.npm` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to have done the trick!

Answer (score 28):

Based on the comment from Linus G Thiel it looks like this fixes the issue:

> Looks like you may have done a `sudo npm install ...` without `-g`, i.e.
>   installed npm packages in your home as the root user. Either clear
>   your `.npm` directory or `chown -R mmarze.mmarze ~/.npm` should fix it.

Comment: It also appears to happen when the first thing you install using npm is done with sudo.

Comment: Just a note, on OSX you need to use ":" (colon) instead of dot between the user and group.

Comment: Note that you might also have to fix permissions for the modules already installed in your project: `chown -R mmarze:mmarze ./node_modules`

Comment: what does `username.username` mean? (In the above case `mmarze.mmarze`)

Comment: You probably will have to put sudo in front of the chown